# Testing Lorentz force on a moving macroscopic charged conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism

Did anyone ever made an experiment with a moving macroscopic charged conductor in a magnetic field testing its deviation due to Lorentz force? I mean: what moves here is the massive charged conductor itself, not only the charges inside it. Would it be feasible with our technology? If it is then why does this force only appears in late 1800's in the scientific literature?

Answer (score 2):

A macroscopic object with charge $q$ will *not* experience a magnetic force of the form $${\bf F}=q(\bf v\times B)$$ if it were to pass through a magnetic field $\bf B$

And of course if there is an electric field, then we have the full form of the Lorentz (electromagnetic) force $${\bf F}=q(\bf E+ v\times B)$$
and charged *particles* experience a local electromagnetic force according to this equation. That is, this equation does *not* work for macroscopic objects.

If we wanted to extend the Lorentz force law to macroscopic objects,  we would need to take into account additional quantities like the polarization (density) $\bf P$ and
magnetization (density) $\bf M$ to be sources of the electromagnetic field and this can severely complicate the situation.

In such a case, the Lorentz force$^1$ (density) takes on a much different form $${\bf F} = (\rho_f −\nabla\cdot {\bf P}){\bf E} + ({\bf J_f}+ \frac{\partial {\bf P}}{\partial t})\times \mu_0{\bf H} − (\nabla\cdot {\bf M}){\bf H} − (\frac{\partial {\bf M}}{\partial t})\times \epsilon_0 {\bf E}$$

where $\rho_f$ and $\bf J_f$ are free charge and current densities respectively, where $${\bf B}= \mu_0 {\bf H} + \bf M$$

Note that the equation for the Lorentz force density requires many assumptions to be valid, and an explanation of this and a derivation can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3383). This equation has been tested, but for very simple systems and the experiment appears to be consistent with the equations.

$^1$ Note that many authors have many other forms to this equation depending on the setup, assumptions, boundary conditions etc., and the equation above for the electromagnetic force density is in the most general form.

Comment: So the Coulomb force applies both to the charges and as a result to the whole charged conductor but the same doesn't apply to the Lorence force? Why this difference?

Comment: Yes, the Coulomb force does. The Lorentz force applied to particles and is not suited to macroscopic bodies. This is determined through experiment. Cheers.

Comment: But they are indeed the same force seen from different frame of referecnces, as shown in Special Relativity.

Comment: But be careful. The magnitude can differ by $\gamma$ (Lorentz factor). The relativistically covariant form of the Lorentz force takes the form $\frac{dp^\alpha}{d\tau}=qF^{\alpha\beta}u_{\beta}$ where $p$ is 4-momentum and $F$ is the electromagnetic tensor with $u$ being a 4-velocity. To learn more about this see any intro text to relativistic electrodynamics or if you like search for "covariant Lorentz force". Cheers.

Comment: Ok but jow does this relate to the different behaviour with macroscopic objects?

Comment: It doesn't. You asked if the Lorentz force is the same in different fames of reference. That is what I answered in the last comment. Cheers.

Comment: I didn't ask "if" they are the same, I asked how comes that they have such difference WRT macroscopic conductors given they are the same thing

Comment: But the statement "_they are indeed the same force seen from different frame of referecnces_" has a different and very specific meaning. But anyway, how things behave microscopically (Lorentz force on particle) hardly ever display the same behavior macroscopically. This is a good example. Another is quantum tunneling. There is no  way you could gently throw a ping-pong ball on a concrete wall and find that ball goes through the wall. In quantum mechanics, this can happen -i.e., objects have a probability of tunneling through barriers. cheers.

Comment: "Different" (meaning) from what?

Comment: Hi again Marco. If what you actually meant was that electric fields and magnetic fields acting on charged particles are both manifestations of the same thing (the electromagnetic field) then yes, this is true and what may seem like an magnetic force in one frame can be the affects of an electric force in a another frame. Sorry if I might have misunderstood your earlier comment. Cheers.

Comment: A charged macroscopic object acts exactly the same as a single charged particle, and would feel a net resultant force, this includes a lorentz force, Obviously.

Comment: What if the conductor is a sphere? Would the espression of the force semplify to a Simple formula?

Comment: If the object is a sphere, then you would need to apply the correct boundary conditions. But I'm sure the result for a spherically symmetric object would be simpler than for say for say a cube, and will certainly be simpler for than for any arbitrary charge distribution with no apparent symmetry. Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps the simple form of the spherical conductor could be just like the formula for point charge?

Comment: I would guess that in the limit $r\rightarrow$ a small number, then the force would approach that of $F=q(E+v\times B)$

Comment: At first you wrote "a macroscopic object will not deflect while moving through a magnetic field due to the Lorentz force" and later you removed this statement. Did you change your mind?

Comment: No. A macroscopic object will not experience a force of the form $F=q(E+v\times B)$ That is what was meant the whole time. But come to think about it, I agree the initial wording was ambiguous. Thanks.

Comment: The macroscopic object will actually deflect, right?

Comment: Yes, but not according to the Lorentz force  $F=q(E+v\times B)$ Again this is for particles. It will follow the more complicated deflection according to the equation I have above for the Lorentz force density. Cheers.